# Insert Hyphon Every Two Characters Batch

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, command-line, windows-7, command-prompt

I am using a wake-on-LAN application on some machines at work and I am creating a script to test it on a lab.

Unfortunately, the application only reads MAC addresses (from a .csv file) without the hyphon, and, in order to check whether or not a machine has been "woken up", the machine needs to be pinged. I have found a way using ARP, however, the MAC address needs to have the hyphon back in it to be found in the ARP table.

Basically, I need to be able to insert a hyphon every two characters (preferably during the script) in the MAC address, so, the transition will be as follows:

XXXXXXXXXXXX -> XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX

The script reads:

```
for /f %%a in (macaddresses.csv) do (
    start "" wol.exe %%a
    :: CONVERSION HERE
    for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims= " %%i in ('arp -a ^| find /i "%%a"') do (
        ping %%i
        if %errorlevel% EQU 0 (
            echo MAC address %%a woken up.
            set /a i+=1
        ) else (
            echo MAC address %%a not woken up.
        )
    )
)
```

I have searched everywhere and found only how to add or remove characters from the end of a string or from a word.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to get what I wanted by an incremental removal of characters:

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
for /f %%a in (macaddresses.csv) do (
    start "" wol.exe %%a
    set mac=%%a
    set mac=!mac:~0,-10!-!mac:~2,-8!-!mac:~4,-6!-!mac:~6,-4!-!mac:~8,-2!-!mac:~10!
    for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims= " %%i in ('arp -a ^| find /i "!mac!"') do (
        ping %%i
        if %errorlevel% EQU 0 (
            echo MAC address !mac! woken up.
            set /a i+=1
        ) else (
            echo MAC address !mac! not woken up.
        )
    )
)
endlocal
```